# C# - Can't receive UDP on second computer

Tags: c#, udp

I can send UDP messages from one computer to itself on a certain port but I can't send this messages from one computer to another in the same lan. I am pretty new to C# and I am also new to network programming so the solution is probably easy...

I have tried an example from Microsoft Docs and did only small changes. (names, etc.)

Both codes run as seperate programs.

```
//RECEIVE
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class UDPListener
{
private const int listenPort = 11000;

private static void Listen()
{
    UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
    IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");
            byte[] receivebytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivebytes, 0, receivebytes.Length));
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        listener.Close();
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Listen();
}
}
```

```
 //SEND
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,        SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    //192.168.2.5 is the IP Address of the receiving computer
    IPAddress broadcast = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.5");

    byte[] bytestosend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi");
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(broadcast, 11000);

    socket.SendTo(bytestosend, ep);

    Console.WriteLine("bytestosend were send");
}
}
```

The sending program tells me that the message was sent but the receiving program gives no output.

EDIT 1: The Ressource Manager said that on the receiving computer was no network activity while on the sending computer is actually sending something.

EDIT 2: I tried my applications in an other network and it worked fine. I did some research and I found that sometimes routers don't allow udp broadcasts through a subnet (or anything similar...). So I assume it might be my router. (unfortunately I can not access it's settings.) So I think the problem has resolved itself!

Comment: Sorry for the bad indenting!

Comment: Might seem like a stupid question, but did you turn your firewall off on both computers? Or at least add an exception for UDP port 11000?

Comment: Yes I allowed it.

Comment: Use tools like Wireshark to actually monitor the packets on the wire. That's much better than guessing around.

Comment: I think it was just my router because it worked in an other system. See Edit 2.